# ASP.NET adding js file on page load

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to add specific js files to the page.
On `Page_Load`, I'm trying this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("MyTab", HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "\\scripts\\" + tabName);
```

It doesn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this solution that will always work. use:

```
Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this without the need to load it in the code-behind:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="sm" runat="server">
   <Scripts>
     <asp:ScriptReference Path="./script.js" />
   </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

If you want to add or change the script file at runtime, just leave the ScriptManager in your  mark-up and access it like this:

```
   ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
   if (Smgr != null) 
   {
     ScriptReference sr = new ScriptReference();
     sr.Path = "~/Scripts/Script.js";
     sm.Scripts.Add(sr);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not using `"MyTab"` anywhere else to register scripts. It's [a key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2552td66.aspx) for the script.

Also `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` will return [the physical path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainapppath.aspx), which makes me think it could return for example `C:\Program Files\...` which won't work for people visiting the site.

Maybe try:

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude("MyTab", Page.ResolveClientUrl("~\\scripts\\" + tabName));
```